Manim only plays one of two simultaneous animations, no matter how I try
I am trying to create an animation of a rotating wheel (a circle with some squares attached to it)
I am trying to do so by having the circle rotate and at the same time sliding, however, it either only rotates or it only slides. Or it slides and then it rotates, everything but sliding and rotating at the same time, which is what would sell the illusion of the wheel moving on the ground.
The current version of the code can be seen below but I have tried many methods, including:
self.play(rotation, slide, run_time = 4
or
self.play(AnimationGroup(rotation, slide, lag_ratio=0), run_time=4)

from manim import *
import numpy as np
class TwoDShapes(Scene):
def construct(self):
circle = Circle(radius=3).shift(LEFT * 4)
    points = []
    squares = []
    
    num_squares = 20
    angle_increment = 2 * PI / num_squares  
   
    for i in range(num_squares):
        points.append(circle.point_at_angle(angle_increment * i))

        square = Square(side_length=0.25)
        square.move_to(points[i])
        squares.append(square)

    START = (-8, -3, 0)
    END = (8, -3, 0)
    line = Line(START, END)

    self.play(Create(line))
    self.play(Create(circle))

    for k in range(num_squares): 
        self.play(Create(squares[k], run_time=0.2))
        
    for k in range(num_squares): 
        self.play(Rotate(squares[k], angle_increment * k, run_time=0.2))

   
    wheel = Group(*squares, circle)

    rotation_animation = wheel.animate.rotate(4*2*PI) 
    shift_animation = wheel.animate.shift(RIGHT * 8)  

    self.play(shift_animation, run_time=4)
    self.wait(0.1)
    self.play(rotation_animation, run_time=3.9)

    self.wait(1)

    text = Text("Why won't it rotate? :(").move_to(LEFT * 3)
    self.play(Write(text))

    self.wait(1)



Why your current approach(es) isn't working
First things first: calling multiple, simultaneous animations that apply to the same VMobject doesn't work. That applies regardless of whether you use an AnimationGroup(). So neither,
self.play(
    Rotate(example_mobject, PI),
    example_mobject.animate.shift(RIGHT)
)

nor,
self.play(
    AnimationGroup(
        Rotate(example_mobject, PI),
        example_mobject.animate.shift(RIGHT),
        lag_ratio=0.0
    )
)

would work under any circumstances, i.e., it's nothing specific to the case of Rotate() and .animate.shift(RIGHT) interacting. Typically, both of the above calls to the play() method will result in only the second (or in general, the lattermost) animation actually being played. It should be noted that neither option causes an exception to be raised, though.
The reason why this approach doesn't work is because manim needs to make certain assumptions in order to play a pre-defined animation, such as .rotate() and .shift(). For example, if the VMobject is moving to the RIGHT from frame-to-frame, then the center of rotation pertaining to the (hypothetically simultaneous) rotation animation is constantly changing from frame-to-frame as well. It's not inconceivable that that could be accounted for, but the point is: the default Rotate() animation doesn't account for such changes. You could apply a similar argument to explain the "incompatibility" of any other pair of simultaneous animations, too, of course.
This is loosely corroborated here by the OP's reply to the first commenter, in which they make a similar point to that which I made above.
So, in short: it's not like you're missing some sort of trick; it's just not how manim is designed to render animations.
Solution: How to animate your particular problem correctly
Firstly, I tweaked and extended some of your constants, for the purposes of generalisation and ease of making quick changes.
RADIUS = 2.5
LINE_LENGTH = 14
START = 7*LEFT + 3*DOWN
END = START + LINE_LENGTH * RIGHT
line = Line(START, END)
wheel = VGroup().add(Circle(radius=RADIUS).move_to(START + RADIUS * UR))

num_squares = 20
angle_increment = 2*PI / num_squares
points = []

for i in range(num_squares):
    points.append(wheel[0].point_at_angle(i * angle_increment))
    square = Square(side_length=RADIUS/12)
    square.move_to(points[i]).rotate(i * angle_increment)
    wheel.add(square)

You can get surprisingly close to a good solution using .generate_target() followed by MoveToTarget(),
wheel.generate_target()
wheel.target.shift((LINE_LENGTH - 2*RADIUS) * RIGHT).rotate(-(LINE_LENGTH - 2*RADIUS) / RADIUS)
self.play(
    MoveToTarget(wheel),
    run_time=5.0
)

Advantages: this is very concise in terms of lines of code, and clearly it uses pre-existing animations.
Disadvantages: However, due to a quirk of the .animate.rotate() method (that even I don't fully understand, by the way!), this implemention results in the wheel seemingly "contracting" as it rolls - and as a consequence, it levitates off the ground (the line) as it moves along!
The only real way to achieve the visual illusion of a wheel rolling along the line (at least as far as I've understood your query) is to write a custom animation.
I've written a custom animation called RollWheelAlongLine() for you that I think fulfils the requirements: please see the full code block below. I've also written a simple demonstration scene called RotatingWheel(), which mimics the (intended) output of your original code snippet in the question.
import numpy as np
from manim import *


class RollWheelAlongLine(Animation):
    def __init__(
            self, mobject: VMobject, how_far_to_roll: float,
            roll_direction: Vector = RIGHT, **kwargs
        ):
        super().__init__(mobject, **kwargs)
        self.how_far_to_roll = how_far_to_roll
        self.roll_direction = roll_direction
        self.start_position = self.mobject.get_center()

        # Assume that the first element of the mobject (VGroup) is a Circle, or at the very least, a Polygon of some sort
        self.radius = self.mobject[0].get_arc_length(255) / (2*PI)
        self.current_rotation = 0.0

        # evaluate the angle of rotation required, CW or CCW depending on roll direction
        if np.array_equal(self.roll_direction, LEFT) or np.array_equal(self.roll_direction, DOWN):
            self.theta = self.how_far_to_roll / self.radius
        elif np.array_equal(self.roll_direction, RIGHT) or np.array_equal(self.roll_direction, UP):
            self.theta = -self.how_far_to_roll / self.radius
        else:
            self.theta = 0.0
    
    def interpolate_mobject(self, alpha: float) -> None:
        # when you overwrite the interpolate_mobject method, you must manually apply any rate functions
        alpha = self.rate_func(alpha)
        angle = alpha * self.theta

        self.mobject.rotate(angle - self.current_rotation)
        self.mobject.move_to(self.start_position + alpha * self.how_far_to_roll * self.roll_direction)
        self.current_rotation = angle


class RotatingWheel(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        RADIUS = 2.5
        LINE_LENGTH = 14
        START = 7*LEFT + 3*DOWN
        END = START + LINE_LENGTH * RIGHT
        line = Line(START, END)
        wheel = VGroup().add(Circle(radius=RADIUS).move_to(START + RADIUS * UR))

        num_squares = 20
        angle_increment = 2*PI / num_squares
        points = []

        for i in range(num_squares):
            points.append(wheel[0].point_at_angle(i * angle_increment))
            square = Square(side_length=RADIUS/12)
            square.move_to(points[i]).rotate(i * angle_increment)
            wheel.add(square)

        self.play(Create(line, run_time=1.5))
        self.play(Create(wheel[0], run_time=1.5))

        self.play(
            AnimationGroup(
                *[Create(sq) for sq in wheel[1:]],
                lag_ratio=0.05
            ),
            run_time=2.0
        )

        self.wait(0.5)

        self.play(
            RollWheelAlongLine(
                wheel,
                LINE_LENGTH - 2*RADIUS  # use default values for the remaining parameters
            ),
            run_time=5.0
        )

        self.wait(2.0)

The Bottom Line (TL;DR)
After copying and pasting the code block above, running,
manim -pqh <filename>.py RotatingWheel
will produce the output you were originally looking for all along.
Happy manimating!
